# Solving the differential equation $(V(b)-b)V'(b) = V(b)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hoping that someone can help me understand the steps throughout the math of the following question. The question is based on auction theory:

I am given that two players valuation are both uniformly distributed on the interval [0,1]. Each players bid is a function of his valuation $b(v)$. Suppose that there exists an inverse function $V(b)$ which gives the valuation of someone who bids $b$. Eventually reaching the point,

$(V(b)-b)V'(b) = V(b)$

At which point the differential equation is solved to show,

$V(b) = b + \sqrt{b^2 + 2C}$

However I cannot seem to prove this result. My integration skills are rather weak and I have been approaching it trying to do integration by parts. However, I am starting to think that my struggle is with the uniform distribution part.

Any tips/help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Use the change of function $$W(b)=V(b)-b$$ and rejoice...

Comment: This can be put in the form of an [exact equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation).